# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors after ic_launcher_rounded

Tags: android

ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Hi, I removed ic_launcher_rounded direcory by mistake from my project. After then I tried to add again. Now, I have ic_launcher_rounded directory but I have androidmanifest.xml error. And i could not solve that issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.projectname">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Signup_Form">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:5 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 4 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

Comment: `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` does this exist in your main manifest?

Comment: Go through details: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge

Comment: No but I added now, problem is continue.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

to this

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: I did but, no different.

Comment: delete that rounded one directory then ? I think that is what causing the issue

Comment: but that is a default directory. also i tried but no different :(

Comment: Did you try Invalidate caches and restart